# JmsListener called again and again when a error happen in the method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jms, spring-jms

In a spring boot application, I have a class with jms listener.

```
public class PaymentNotification{

    @JmsListener(destination="payment")
    public void receive(String payload) throws Exception{
        //mapstring conversion
        .... 

        paymentEvent = billingService.insert(paymentEvent); //transactional method
 
        //call rest...

        
        billingService.save(paymentEvent);

        //send info to jms

    }
 

}
```

I saw then when a error happen, data is inserted in the database, that ok, but it's like receive method is called again and again... but queue is empty when I check on the server.

If there is an error, I don't want method is called again, Is there something for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JMS Message Headers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnces/index.html) might contain additional information to help with your processing. In particular `JMSRedelivered` could be of some value. The [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSRedelivered()) states that "If a client receives a message with the JMSRedelivered field set, it is likely, but not guaranteed, that this message was delivered earlier but that its receipt was not acknowledged at that time."

I ran the following code to explore what was available in my configuration (Spring Boot with IBM MQ).

```java
    @JmsListener(destination="DEV.QUEUE.1")
        public void receive(Message message) throws Exception{
 
            for (Enumeration<String> e = message.getPropertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());    

        }
```

From here I could find `JMSXDeliveryCount` is available in [JMS 2.0](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html). If that property is not available, then you may well find something similar for your own configuration.

One strategy would be to use `JMSXDeliveryCount`, a vendor specific property or maybe `JMSRedelivered` (if suitable for your needs) as a way to check before you process the message. Typically, the message would be sent to a specific blackout queue where the redelivery count exceeds a set threshold.

Depending on the messaging provider you are using it might also be possible to configure back out queue processing as properties of the queue.